# How to include third Party dll files in Mono 2.10?

Tags: c#, mono, dllimport

I have developed an windows desktop Application using C# .NET 4 framwork.Now, we are going to using MONO2.10 for cross platform.For sample, I have downloaded the mono 2.10 on windows version and able to run my .net exe.While doing so, Its Working fine and it says error the below mentioned error msg. As per my understanding, I think the DLL Reference is not included properly...

i am using 2 third party dll files in application.

1. Ionic.dll for .net zip library
2. DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll for XML file management.

Please guide me to how to include these dll reference in Mono on windows?

[image: Mono_Error_Msg]

Thanks & Regards,
Saravanan.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is not part of Microsoft .NET or Mono Framework.
Therefore, you just need to either put it in GAC or in the same folder with your application, just like you normally do with third-party components.

Comment: thanks Gaearon! I will try it.Did u see the Error Msg? What it says?is it dll reference missing or something else? Please share your thougths...

Comment: gaearon, I have added Ionic.zip.dll using gacutil successfully.But i can't able to put the reference of DocumentFormat.openXml.dll file.   It says " Failure adding assembly c:\Program Files\Open XML SDK\V2.0\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll to the cache: Strong name cannot be verified for delay-signed assembly". What will be the mistake here?

Comment: The assembly has not been signed, and assemblies have to be signed before they can be added to the GAC.  Either sign the assembly or just put it in the same folder as your application.

Comment: @jpobst: I have put the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll file in the same folder with my application.But Still the above error message dialog box is appeared.What i do next?

Comment: It must be in the same folder with your `exe` file. Is it?

Comment: yes... I have installed open xml sdk 2.0 and it is located in c:\program files\open xml sdk\v2\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll. So, I placed my application exe file in the same location mentioned above.(c:\program files\open xml sdk\v2\lib\CDA_Server_21Sep.exe).But still that error raising... "Could not open the selected folder.Could not load file or assembly DocumentFormat.OpenXml,version=2.0.5022.0 culture=netural publickeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or one of its assembilies.

Comment: Then show us code. This dialog box is not standard. Does your code load this assembly via Reflection or smth?

Comment: @ Gaearon: I have added the dll's through project explorer(visual studio 2010 express) window by specifying namespace.So, From that namespace,we are using dll functions...